# How to get data from a sub-collection in Firestore on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have my Firestore database in the following way:

[Image Database Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI2Ih.png)

I been try this to get the value of sub-collection:

```
  FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference bulletinRef = rootRef.collection("facultades").document("3QE27w19sttNvx1sGoqR").collection("escuelas").document("0");
    bulletinRef.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA" + "===" + document.getData());
                    }
                }
            });
```

But this does return null:
[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZIwr.png)

Please help me.

Comment: You need to pass the document id to `document()`.  If you don't do that, then you are effectively trying to read a document with some unknown random ID.  That will certainly never give you a result.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson you mean something like this: `CollectionReference bulletinRef = rootRef.collection("facultades").document("3QE27w19sttNvx1sGoqR").collection("escuelas");`
I get the same result

Comment: Hi there, do you get any result within your for loop at all? What do you get when you try to print the document object item only (without the getString part)?

Comment: You mean somethin like this  `Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData().values()); `
but it's does not return something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `null` because `escuelas` is **not** a subcollection, it is an array that holds objects of type `HashMap`. So the following line of code:

```
DocumentReference bulletinRef = rootRef.collection("facultades").document("3QE27w19sttNvx1sGoqR")
    .collection("escuelas").document("0");
```

Will never work. If you want to get the data within the `escuelas` array, please note that `array` type fields arrive from the Cloud Firestore database as a `List` of maps. So please use the following lines of code:

```
rootRef.collection("facultades").document("3QE27w19sttNvx1sGoqR").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                List<Object> list = (List<Object>) document.get("escuelas");
                //Iterate throught the list and get the data
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please also note that while iterating, each element that you get from the list is of type `HashMap`. So you'll need to iterate again to get the corresponding data within each `HashMap` object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this really helped me, I used this code to iterate

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    rootRef.collection("facultades").document("3QE27w19sttNvx1sGoqR")
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    List<Object> list = (List<Object>) document.get("escuelas");
                    //Iterate throught the list and get the data

                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("key2", list.toString());
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

this is the result: [Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPgCO.png)

But i feel confused, how ca I get just this:

[image database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YyvD.png)

Facultades> all documents> escuelas > name

Comment: You should iterate again, so you can get the corresponding nested data.